# How to create a function that passes pandas columns into it?

Tags: python, pandas

I am importing a csv that looks like this. The possible values are $ and net

`Type1,Type2,Type3
 $,,
 $,net,
 net,$,$`

I currently have it in a pandas dataframe and am wondering how I can map $ and net to different values.

I want to map $ -> DEPOSIT and net to -> NET DEP

I am passing the column into a function

```
def directDeposit(var):
    for value in var: 
        var.astype(str)
        if value == '$':
            var = value.map({'$':'DEPOSIT'})

df['type1'] = directDeposit(df['type1'])`
```

Because there are three possible types from the csv I wanted to be able to pass the type I was testing into the function so that I could repeat it for all 3. I'm not really sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do this:

```
df['type1'] = df['type1'].map({'net': 'NET DEP', '$': 'DEPOSIT', '': "No value assigned"})
```

When you create a function that takes a Pandas Series as an input, you don't have to loop over it. Pandas will do that for you.

Comment: If i use the single line of code, is there a way to allow blanks to still be passed instead of defaulting to "NET DEP" if there is a blank

Comment: Then I get this value error. ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: Look at my new response. Should work fine.

Comment: Since you are keen on using map, Then it's `df['type1'].map({'net': 'NET DEP', '$': 'DEPOSIT'}).fillna(df['type1'])`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) method:

```
df.replace({'$': 'DEPOSIT', 'net': 'NET DEP'})
```